# Symfony2 - Assetic: Declaring multiple images as assets

Tags: symfony, web, assets, assetic

Since we use *assetic* to manage the site's assets, we need to **dump all images** regardless if they are declared on a twig template due to most of them are used dynamically.

The way to afford this, I think, is **declaring them as assets on assetic configuration**, but it is a tedious task.

Does anybody know how to declare multiple image as assets in an elegant way?

Thanks